# How to get WorkflowMax API Keys?

Tags: xero-api

Workflow max website not showing any details regarding API keys. Is there any way to get the necessary API keys?

Answer (score 0):

I not from the WorkflowMax team but according to the [docs](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/workflowmax/overview-workflowmax#authentication): All new connections to the WorkflowMax API must use OAuth 2.0. Create a connection to a WorkflowMax account by selecting a WorkflowMax scope.